# Home sharing with an ethernet-connected PC

Tags: itunes, wifi, ethernet, home-sharing, remote.app

When my PC and my iPhone are connected to the same Wi-Fi network, I can access my shared library with the Remote app. It works as advertised.

But if I connect my PC through an ethernet cable, the library does not appear in Remote.

**My configuration:**

- A Netgear switch is connected to my ISP box.
- A Wi-Fi mesh (Netgear Orbi) is connected to that switch.
- My PC is connected to that switch.
- My iPhone is connected to the Wi-Fi mesh.

**What I noticed:**
If I connect my PC to the Wi-Fi, then open Remote and start playing a song from the shared library, and finally re-plug the ethernet cable into my PC, Remote continues to see my shared library (even if I kill the app and immediately relaunch it).
From this point, it seems to work for a while but at some point, Remote does not see the shared library anymore.

I know the doc says both devices should be on the same Wi-Fi network but since I somehow made it work through ethernet, I'm wondering if it could also work without having to unplug my PC first.

**UPDATE:** Following David Andersen's track, I tried disabling Wi-Fi as soon as I re-plug the ethernet cable and Remote lose connection immediately. So, I guess it never worked through ethernet (it just work until the PC does the actual switch from Wi-Fi to ethernet). But my question remains: Is there a way I can make it work?

Comment: If the Netgear Orbi has a router enabled, then the ethernet connection would be on a different LAN than the iPhone. I assume when you connect by ethernet, the WiFi connection is still enabled on the Mac. At some point, macOS is going to choose ethernet over WiFi and maybe that is when Remote does not see the shared library anymore.

Comment: It's a PC but that should not be relevant. But you mean the computer can be connected through ethernet *and* Wi-Fi at the same time?

Comment: You can enable both ethernet and WiFi. The internet is built on redundancy. The computer will choose which ever is fastest.